# Is it possible for a decision tree to have increasing error as dataset gets larger?

Tags: machine-learning, cart

By convention I would expect having more data would decrease the error. 
I get the following results in accuracy, in increments of 1000 training data(every row is an additional 1000 training data):

```
validation    training
0.98406374502 1.0
0.918163672655 0.985333333333
0.888149134487 0.962222222222
0.881118881119 0.931
0.901678657074 0.962933333333
0.863424383744 0.886666666667
0.841233580811 0.886095238095
0.855572213893 0.882
0.862727676588 0.900444444444
0.790883646541 0.829733333333
0.806615776081 0.845939393939
0.808063978674 0.859777777778
0.79698554291 0.859487179487
0.778634675807 0.842
```

Is it just because my data set is "too easy"? I'm using the data here:
https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/EEG+Eye+State

Comment: How are you choosing the validation set? In general, if you can post a minimal example of code showing this behavior, it'll be much easier for us to diagnose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you shuffling the order of the data before subsetting it?

It seems that the dataset's order is not random; the first chunk of lines in [the data file](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/00264/EEG%20Eye%20State.arff) all have `eyeDetection` of 0, then the next chunk 1, then repeat. Here's a plot of that attribute, in dataset order:

[image]

Certain lengths of data subsetting will thus give different proportions of the labels, but here the ratio doesn't seem to be too crazily unbalanced for chunks of length divisible by 1000, so that's probably not it.

But, since the examples aren't in random order, it's reasonable to expect that they may be in an order correlated with what *kind* of example they are. (Perhaps the dataset is sorted by different ways that the data was collected.)

I'll illustrate that this is true by running a k-means clustering on the standardized dataset, then seeing that the prevalence of assignment to each cluster varies over time. The following plot shows $\log_{10}(\text{count} + 1)$ for each of the 8 k-means clusters within each of 50 bins of the data, in file order. The horizontal axis is data order, each vertical block is a cluster. You can clearly see that it changes over time.

[image]

So, if you're not shuffling the data first, it's very possible that subsetting the data is actually giving you the easy examples first, or at least a much smaller variety of examples.

Comment: Very good point, and a popular mistake.

Answer (score 3):

More data will also have more *anomalies*.

It is one kind of overfitting that your classifier tries hard to make every training example perfect, when it should generalize instead.

If you prune your decision tree (stopping branches with too few elements, to prevent it from learning from single anomalies), does it behave more as you had expected?

Comment: i'm using scikit learn's decisiontreeclassifier. To prune the tree, I limited the max_Depth parameter of the tree. I found this max depth parameter with cross validation. Whatever depth gets me the best accuracy is picked.  Even with pruned trees I'm still getting the pattern above.